# JavaFX: how do you edit existing TableView entries

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have figured out how to create a `TableView` and how to add content to it but I am confused as to how to edit existing content.

In this app I have set it up so a person can add player names and certain stats to the tableview but I want to now be able to add a random roll and add the dex and other modifiers to it and populate the tableview with it. This would reside in the `rollInitBtnClicked()` module.

Please help me understand what I need to do.

This is my `Main` class.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

TextField playerName;
TextField dexMod;
TextField otherMod;
TableView<Players> playersTable;
Button addPlayerBtn;
Button rollInitBtn;
Button delPlayerBtn;


public static void main(String[] args){

    launch(args);


}


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    primaryStage.setTitle("Initiative");

    // TextField so the user can enter a players Name
    playerName = new TextField();
    playerName.setPrefSize(200, 20);
    playerName.setPromptText("Player Name");
    //playerName.setFocusTraversable(false);

    // TextField so the user can enter the players dex mod
    dexMod = new TextField();
    dexMod.setPrefSize(50, 20);
    dexMod.setPromptText("Dex");
    //dexMod.setFocusTraversable(false);

    // TextField so the user can enter the players other mods
    otherMod = new TextField();
    otherMod.setPrefSize(50, 20);
    otherMod.setPromptText("Other");
    //otherMod.setFocusTraversable(false);


    addPlayerBtn = new Button("Add Player"); 
    addPlayerBtn.setOnAction(e -> addPlayerBtnClicked());

    delPlayerBtn = new Button("Delete Player"); 
    delPlayerBtn.setOnAction(e -> delPlayerBtnClicked());

    rollInitBtn = new Button("Roll Initiative"); 
    rollInitBtn.setOnAction(e -> rollInitBtnClicked());



    //TableView Name Columns
    TableColumn<Players, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    nameColumn.setMinWidth(200);
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    //TableView dexMod Columns
    TableColumn<Players, String> dexColumn = new TableColumn<>("Dex Mod");
    dexColumn.setMinWidth(50);
    dexColumn.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
    dexColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dexMod"));

    //TableView otherMod Columns
    TableColumn<Players, String> otherColumn = new TableColumn<>("Other Mods");
    otherColumn.setMinWidth(50);
    otherColumn.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
    otherColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("otherMod"));

    //TableView roll Columns
    TableColumn<Players, String> rollColumn = new TableColumn<>("Die Roll");
    rollColumn.setMinWidth(50);
    rollColumn.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
    rollColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("roll"));

    //TableView total Columns
    TableColumn<Players, String> totalColumn = new TableColumn<>("Total");
    totalColumn.setMinWidth(50);
    totalColumn.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
    totalColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("total"));



    playersTable = new TableView<>();
    playersTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    playersTable.setItems(getPlayers());
    playersTable.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, dexColumn, otherColumn, rollColumn, totalColumn);



    HBox hLayout = new HBox();
    hLayout.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));         // sets the padding on the top right left and bottom of the layout
    hLayout.setSpacing(10);                                 // sets the spacing between the TextFields and buttons
    hLayout.getChildren().addAll(playerName, dexMod, otherMod, addPlayerBtn, rollInitBtn, delPlayerBtn);


    VBox vLayout = new VBox();
    vLayout.getChildren().addAll(playersTable, hLayout);


    Scene mainScene = new Scene(vLayout, 800, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
    primaryStage.show();

}


// What happens when the user clicks the Add Player button
public void addPlayerBtnClicked() {

    Players players = new Players();
    players.setName(playerName.getText());
    players.setDexMod(Integer.parseInt(dexMod.getText()));
    players.setOtherMod(Integer.parseInt(otherMod.getText()));
    playersTable.getItems().add(players);
    playerName.clear();
    dexMod.clear();
    otherMod.clear();
}

// What happens when the user clicks the Delete Player button
public void delPlayerBtnClicked() {

    ObservableList<Players> playerSelected, allPlayers;
    allPlayers = playersTable.getItems();
    playerSelected = playersTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

    playerSelected.forEach(allPlayers::remove);



}

public void rollInitBtnClicked() {

    Players players = new Players();
    ObservableList<Players> playerSelected, allPlayers;
    allPlayers = playersTable.getItems();
    playerSelected = playersTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

    players.setRoll((int)Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20));

}



public ObservableList<Players> getPlayers(){
    ObservableList<Players> players = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    return players;
}

}
```

The following lives in a class named `Players`.

```
public class Players {

private String name;
private int dexMod;
private int otherMod;
private int roll;
private int total;


// default method to enter default data
public Players(){

}

// overloaded method to enter data that is handed to it
public Players(String name, int dexMod, int otherMod, int roll, int total){

    this.name = name;
    this.dexMod = dexMod;
    this.otherMod = otherMod;
    this.roll = roll;
    this.total = total;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getDexMod() {
    return dexMod;
}

public void setDexMod(int dexMod) {
    this.dexMod = dexMod;
}

public int getOtherMod() {
    return otherMod;
}

public void setOtherMod(int otherMod) {
    this.otherMod = otherMod;
}

public int getRoll() {
    return roll;
}

public void setRoll(int roll) {
    this.roll = roll;
}

public int getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `TableView` to be notified of modifications, you need to make a `ObservableValue` wrapping the property value available that is notified of modifications. `PropertyValueFactory` uses a method `<propertyName>Property()` to retrieve this `ObservableValue`. If no such method exists, it uses the getter; However in this case the `TableView` not notified of any modification. Furthermore the `total` property should not be modifiable on it's own.

Starting with JavaFX 8u60 there is a `refresh` method in `TableView`, which would allow you to manually trigger a refresh:

```
private final Random random = new Random();

public void rollInitBtnClicked() {
    List<Players> targets = playersTable.getItems();

    for (Players p : targets) {
        p.setRoll(random.nextInt(20));
        // set total ect...
    }

    // update table
    playersTable.refresh();
}
```

However the "standard approach that is also compatible with older versions of JavaFX would be modifying the properties:

```
private final IntegerProperty roll = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

public int getRoll() {
    return roll.get();
}

public void setRoll(int roll) {
    this.roll.set(roll);
}

public IntegerProperty rollProperty() {
    return this.roll;
}

// same modifications for other int properties
...

private final IntegerBinding total = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> getRoll() + getOtherMod() + getDexMod(), roll, otherMod, dexMod);

public int getTotal() {
    return this.total.get();
}

public IntegerBinding totalProperty() {
    return this.total;
}
```

This would allow you to remove the `refresh` call from the `rollInitBtnClicked` method posted above.

---

#### Additional notes

1. If you're using a class to store the data for a single player, it should not be named `Players`, but `Player`.
2. You're using incorrect type parameters for your `TableColumn`s. This is not important here, since `PropertyValueFactory` works regardless of type parameters, but it could get you into problems, if you use other features of `TableColumn`. The second type parameter should always match the type parameter of the `ObservableValue` returned by the `cellValueFactory`:

   ```
   TableColumn<Players, String> nameColumn
   TableColumn<Players, Number> dexColumn
   TableColumn<Players, Number> otherColumn
   TableColumn<Players, Number> rollColumn
   TableColumn<Players, Number> totalColumn
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I implemented your ideas and I ran into two prominent error. I "fixed" one but im not confident in if it will work the same. your line:

Comment: List<Players> targets = playersTable.getItems(); was giving me and error for List. I changed this to ObservableList and it looks like Eclipse likes that better. However I cannot figure out the error I am getting for your line of code that adds all of the integers up for a total. the method createIntegerBinding() is throwing an error that says "The method createIntegerBinding(Callable<Integer>, Observable...) in the type Bindings is not applicable for the arguments (Callable<Integer>, IntegerProperty, Int, Int)

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to mark the table as editable

```
playersTable.setEditable(true);
```

Also you need to change the cell factory for any editable columns.

```
nameColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

for the integer type columns, you'll also need to specify a converter.

```
otherColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
rollColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
totalColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
```

and fix the declaration from `<Players, String>` to `<Players, Integer>`, i.e.

```
TableColumn<Players, Integer> totalColumn = new TableColumn<>("Total");
```

You should now be able to edit the table by either doing a "long click", or pressing F2, i.e. just like standard applications...

More information can be found in the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the reply but unless i misunderstand this only lets you manually edit fields in a given column. I want to apply a random number to all entries via the roll initiative button press.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood editable. See other answer. You need to javafx properties or refresh (refresh only added in 8u60 btw)